# Erro RestTemplate

Tags: java, api, spring, spring-boot, rest

Galera estou tentando realizar uma consulta em uma API de previsao de tempo porem sempre que vou realizar a consulta me da essa exceção

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute] with root cause
```

Minha controle a onde esta com o RestTemplate esta assim

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String urlFinal = stringBuilder.append(url).append(cidade).append("&appid=").append(apiKey).toString();

    ResponseEntity<WeatherResponseObject> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity(urlFinal, WeatherResponseObject.class);

    System.out.println(entity.getBody());

    return entity.getBody();
```

E por ultimo o retorno do meu WeatherResponseObject

```
public List<BodyWeather> list;
```

Comment: como você está tendo uma exceção IllegalArgumentException faz o seguinte, pega a impressão dessa urlFinal em seu console e verifique se e endpoint está correto.

Comment: Ja realizei esse teste para verificar se o endpoint estava errado, porem ele é gerado corretamente, tambem ja passei a url direto pra verificar se nao era isso

Answer (score 0):

Estranho, esse erro dá a impressão que sua URL está errada, mas como você disse que não está, tenta usar o URIComponentsBuilder. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
                    .fromUriString(openWeatherProperties.getUrl());

builder.queryParam("appid", openWeatherProperties.getAppId());
            
WeatherResponseObject wheater = restTemplate.getForObject(builder.build().toUriString(), WeatherResponseObject.class);
```